# Why do bone rotations spontaneously start changing the bone roll?

Tags: rigging

Normally when I try rotating a bone in edit mode, its bone roll doesn't change. Now all of a sudden, when I rotate a bone about its local x axis, it starts spinning about its local y axis and changes its roll. How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Can you attach a simple blend file that shows this behaviour?